# Visual Studio 2008 PUBLISH installer installs older version

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, setup-project

I decided to use the Publish feature in Visual Studio.
I'm also using the update feature. It worked up till version 1.0.0.6
and now it's just stuck there.

I can uninstall the App but it always re-installs it to that version.
I've actually had a similar problem with the normal Application Setup.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you manually change the version to 1.0.0.7 and see if that helps?

Comment: Actually I'm already on 1.0.1.3 to with all my tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I've found the solution. The software was signed differently and resulted in Windows Vista + 7 not identifying with it or something of the sort.

Comment: Well, could get it working for a while, but ended back up with this problem. The issue is definitely a bug in my Manifest, but more so a bug in VISTA because it only happens there. Will try to figure it out and post here.

Answer (score 1):

Surely 'auto-increment on publish' is checked?

Comment: Just tested on WINXP, so it only happens on VISTA + WINDOWS7

Answer (score 1):

Also tried Clean on project?
Or clear the publish folder and republish?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the ClickOnce manifest files aren't getting generated the way they're supposed to.  You can check this using the [mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28VS.80%29.aspx) utility on the .application and .manifest files.  They will probably point to old versions of your app.  Visual Studio should generate them correctly but if it isn't then as a last resort you can use the mage utility to edit your manifest files so they point to the right versions and deployment files.

Comment: I'm trying this out, but I must admit that I am skeptic because it only happens on Vista & Win7. But anyhow, I'm gonna try

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems:  on development server I use SVN and did an SVN update, which gives me new files.
Then when publishing, I discovered that only 1 .js file was not updated. On development server it was 11k and on published server an older version of 8k remained.

Even after republishing many times, no change.

Then when deleting manually the file on published server, and republish, the new version appeared !!!

This was confirmed by another developer.

So publish cannot be trusted .... :(